# Custom community reset password action gets executed twice

Tags: community, reset-password

we have a requirement to have the following reset password flow:

1. User requests password reset
2. User clicks a link from the email
3. User provides and confirms a new password
4. User gets redirected to a confirmation page

```html
<apex:page id="changePassword" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="ChangePasswordController" title="{!$Label.site.change_password}">
<apex:form id="theForm">
<apex:pageMessages id="error"/>
<apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:1em;">
  <apex:outputLabel rendered="{! !$Site.IsPasswordExpired}" value="{!$Label.site.old_password}" for="oldpsw"/>
  <apex:inputSecret required="true" id="oldpsw" rendered="{! !$Site.IsPasswordExpired}" value="{!oldPassword}"/>
  <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.new_password}" for="psw"/>
  <apex:inputSecret required="true" id="psw" value="{!newPassword}"/>
  <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.verify_new_password}" for="vpsw"/>
  <apex:inputSecret required="true" id="vpsw" value="{!verifyNewPassword}"/>
  <apex:outputText value=""/>
  <apex:commandButton id="cpwbtn" action="{!changePassword}" value="{!$Label.site.change_password}"/>
</apex:panelGrid> 
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex controller:

```jsp
public with sharing class ChangePasswordController {
    public String oldPassword { get; set; }
    public String newPassword { get; set; }
    public String verifyNewPassword { get; set; }

    public PageReference changePassword() {
        if(!Utils.isValid(this.newPassword )){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error, System.Label.invalid_password));
            return null;
        }
        Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldpassword);
        return Page.ChangePasswordSuccessPage;
    }

    public ChangePasswordController() {
    }
}
```

**The issue** is even though redirect is working fine, the `changePassword` method gets invoked twice. Periodically it crashes during one of its execution and the user can not login with their new credentials, even though they have just seen success confirmation page, because first method invocation was successfull and it was enough to get the redirect to success page, but the user's password is already invalid.
We wanted also to add an email confirmation after password change, but due to double method invocation the email also is sent twice. It doesn't matter if i put the email sending logic in the `changePassword` method or in the `action` at the `apex:page` level in the `ChangePasswordSuccessPage` page, it always gets executed twice. I guess it is because the commandButton submits the form and refreshes the page, why does it get invoked second time after refresh, though?!

**I've already tried** to add `rerender="none"` or `oncomplete="return false;"`  to the commandButton or to refresh just part of the page, and in all these cases method executes only once, but redirect to the success page does not happen.
I have also tried to add a boolean property to the page and execute the logic only when the variable is false, no luck.

I am out of ideas how to make it work together

- Redirect the user to the Success Page
- Send an email [only one!] to the user confirming the change